# 1.44 inch ST7735S lcd screen on gpio only white output

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, spi, raspberry-pi-os, lcd

I recently bought an lcd screen on ali express that is attached to the gpio, but the system does not detect it, screen is constantly white and output is only on hdmi. I tried turning spi on raspi-config, nothing happened. I read that I must install something so that it works, I seen some tutorials, but none worked.

This is the screen, I don´t know the brand:
[image]

this is the link where I bought it from: https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/33024972061.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.2742b90aAG2MIm

sorry guys, I did not know this is a brand specific problem, I though every screen for the pi zero needed the same driver.

the tutorial I foloowed that did not work was this one: https://pi0cket.com/tiny-software-for-tinypi/#more-99

Comment: what would help is knowing anything at all about this LCD screen ... like a brand name? model? etc

Comment: do you have a question of some kind?

Comment: your post looks like it was written by a polititian ... lots of words, but no information ... all in all, you did not say anything useful

Comment: ok, updated the question

Comment: From what I saw at Aliexpress link, model of your screen is: ST7735S. You can google the datasheet to see if it's any different than the screen that was used in the tutorial. Of course in case you wanna tinker and in case you can read datasheets. Otherwise simplest solution is to find and buy a compatible screen or even better the same - to be safe - of what you saw in the tutorial. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I got a message from the seller, I´ll post the answer! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seller sent me this:

https://www.waveshare.net/wiki/1.44inch_LCD_HAT?spm=a2g0s.imconversation.0.0.3d073e5fTM9i7J&file=1.44inch_LCD_HAT

I ran the demo in C ( python had an error ) and it worked, but I didn´t have any feedback on the buttons pressed, and now I´m trying to make it mirror the desktop, but I got a "DMA channel assigned by another peripheral" error, trying to debug it.

UPDATE: I was able to make it work using channels 7 and 1 respectively, and the analog mouse is also working but they did not inform that I needed to run:

```
pip install RPi.GPIO
```

I had some trouble making FBCP run on rc.local like not having access to `/dev/mem`, but I erased `rc.local` completely and made it from scratch and it worked, don´t know what was wrong though.

I also had a problem that the screen kept going blank after a few seconds of inactivity, but I solved it buy building FBCP with `DBACKLIGHT_CONTROL=OFF`. The only thing I wasn´t able to fix was the screen size to make it square, because `hdmi_cvt` on `/boot/config.txt` is completely ignored.